# What is the reason for assuming angular momentum is conserved for a moon-planet system where the moon is in an elliptical orbit around the planet?

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws, orbital-motion, planets, moon

I came across a question in the Princeton Review book for AP Physics 1 and then found the same question in the Collegeboard AP Physics course guide. Both have different answers. (See the questions below)

I understand that the distance can be calulcated using conservation of angular momentum, so that leaves just two answer choices. My question is about the reason that conservation of angular momentum can be used.

I know that the gravitational force on the moon is directed towards the planet, but what does that tell me about the conservation of momentum? Nothing... The direction of the gravitational force is NOT perpendicular to the path or velocity of the moon since it's in an elliptical orbit.

On the other hand, [Newton's Third Law is connected to](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0405099.pdf) (or perhaps the basis of) the law of conservation of momentum. So shouldn't the answer be **A** for the Princeton question and **D** for the Collegeboard question? Am I wrong?

See the questions here:

**Princeton Review**
[image: Princeton Review Question]

[image: Princeton Review Answer]

**Collegeboard**

[image: Collegeboard Question]
[image: Collegeboard Answer]

Please help.

Comment: The two questions are exactly the same thing, and have the same answers (choice B). The Princeton review book has an error.

Comment: In general, prep books for high school exams are _full_ of errors, sometimes up to a mistake every single page. They're not written by people who have any deep knowledge, and as you just saw, their practice questions are often made by taking real questions and (incorrectly) copying them.

Comment: If you're ever wondering who's right, <random prep book> or College Board, it's always the latter.

Comment: Thanks. But can I know why B is the correct answer? How does the direction of the gravitational force justify the conservation of momentum?

Comment: @MSayanvala The torque exerted by a force is given by $\tau = \vec{r}\times\vec{F}$. Because the force $\vec{F}$ is directed along the position vector $\vec{r}$ this cross-product vanishes and hence there is no torque.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get it. I understand if it were a circular path, but the position and the force vectors are not always in the same direction for an elliptical orbit, no?

Comment: If the position vector is taken from the centre of mass of the system...

Comment: And besides, that gives the net torque on the moon alone. We know that the speed and thus momentum of the moon alone is not conserved. Shouldn't we be looking to show that the net torque of the system is zero?

Comment: As i noted in my comment and as repeated by the answer of @e4f5 the net torque is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

If your frame of reference is placed on the center of mass of the planet, there is no torque exerted on the moon ($\mathbb{r}\parallel\mathbb{F}$), so angular momentum is conserved. At the points A and B the velocity of the moon is orthogonal to its position vector, so the magnitude of the angular momentum vector is
$$|L|=m r_A  v_A=mr_ B v_B.$$
At this point you just solve for $r_B$.
We used conservation of angular momentum and the fact that the force on the moon points towards the planet, so **B** is the right alternative.